# ReactJS + Material-UI: How to set current date as default value using Material-UI's <DatePicker>?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, redux, material-ui

Currently I'm using ReactJS + Material-UI's `<DatePicker>` (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker), and would like to have today's current date set as the default/initial value for the `<DatePicker>`. How can I go about doing so?

Current set up:

```
<DatePicker
  autoOk={true}
  hintText="Select Date"
  value={inputs.dateValue}
  onChange={this.handleDatechange}
/>
```

Answer (score 9):

Yoy can do something like this

```
this.state={
    date : new Date()
}

handleDatechange(event,date){
    this.setState({date: date})
}

<DatePicker
  autoOk={true}
  hintText="Select Date"
  value={this.state.date}
  onChange={this.handleDatechange}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

DatePickers default behaviour is to start on today's date.  The only reason this wouldn't be the case is if you pass in either a defaultDate prop, or a value prop with a different date.

In your case you are passing value as inputs.dateValue, so this will be the initial value.  You just need to ensure that the value of inputs.dateValue is set to today's date, for example,

```
inputs.dateValue = new Date();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set it like that

```
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs'
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

. 
.
.

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} >
    <DatePicker defaultValue={dayjs(new Date())} />

</LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: This will work if component is not controlled.
value={inputs.dateValue || dayjs(new Date())} should work.

Answer (score 1):

In case using [Redux-Form](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-initialvalues-object-lt-string-string-gt-code-optional-), like me, you can set the default in this way

In container set initialValues:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'DateForm', 
    initialValues: { use_end_date: new Date() }
})(DateFormComponent);
```

For Field in component:

```
<Field
  name="use_end_date"
  component={ReduxMaterialDatePicker}
  margin="none"
/>
```